# Contact forms not sending mails

Tags: email, contact

I used two plugins, contact form7 and pirate form, both display the message of succes but nothing coming in my inbox. Alsto tried the SMTP with google and hotmail but i recive a message that someone tried to login on my account.

Comment: Are you using the WP Mail SMTP plugin?

Comment: Yes i tried that plugin and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SMTP and Gmail, you will need turn on 2 step verification, then create an App specific password in security panel of google account. Use your email and that password as login credential. You'll also need use TSL or SSL for SMTP.

Hope this help!

Comment: I dont have the money for a google App account :/, im actually making my own theme and saving the money for my hosting this is frustrating

Comment: Nope, you can do it with free Gmail account.